# Changing Heap size of Jmeter at Run time

Tags: jmeter, runtime, heap-size

I want to change the heap size of `jmeter` at run time. Can you kindly suggest how I can achieve it

I used the below command, but looks like whatever heap I'm setting not effective.

I used:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

to check the alloacted memory and it returned

> 9544663040

Looks like I am doing something wrong.

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms2g -Xmx6g" /tui/endeca/endeca/ToolsAndFrameworks/jmeter/app/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t /tui/endeca/endeca/ToolsAndFrameworks/Script/TH/TH_BitBucket_Augu3_Lg.jmx
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting JVM heap size at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763295/setting-jvm-heap-size-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your way of checking maximum heap is correct, I believe you should be using [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html) to check effective parameters, in particular [MemoryPoolMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html)

Quick way to check whether your argument got applied or not is the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) (use it in any of [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223))

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean

def runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean()
def arguments = runtimeMxBean.getInputArguments()

for (argument in arguments) {
    println('Effective JVM argument: ' + argument)
}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Heap Check]

Comment: Big Thank you Dmitri:). I can check the heap now:)

Comment: JVM_ARGS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g"

JMETER_HOME=/tui/endeca/endeca/ToolsAndFrameworks/jmeter/app/apache-jmeter-3.1/

export JVM_ARGS
export JAVA_HOME

echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $JVM_ARGS
 update in jmeter.sh file as java -server $JVM_ARGS -jar `dirname $0`/ApacheJMeter.jar "$@"
#export JMETER_HOME
$JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t "/tui/endeca/endeca/ToolsAndFrameworks/Script/TH/TH_BitBucket_Augu3_Lg.jmx"